# Изменение стилей в макете Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

недавно начал изучать Bootstrap и для более подробного изучения решил использовать уже доступный макет "startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages" и столкнулся с невозможностью редактировать имеющиеся там Sass файлы, даже если их удалить ничего не изменяется и стили все-равно используются, а по идее такого же не должно быть!?

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink- 
to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>SB Admin 2 - Dashboard</title>

<!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
<link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/navs/_global.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/navs/_sidebar.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/navs/_topbar.scss">

</head>
```

Comment: скорей всего стили скешировались браузером. Попробуйте очистить кеш и перезагрузить страницу

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, увы, не помогло. Да и не думаю что это как-нибудь связано с браузером, если даже стили полностью удалить стили они все-равно будут использоваться, как будто все они описаны в css/sb-admin-2.min.css

Comment: вам надо убрать min и подключить `scss/bootstrap.scss` поскольку там все завязано на импортах, миксинах и т.д. Если и это не выйдет. То тогда лучше собирать свой css файл из scss с помощью gulp или webpack

Comment: @DmitryKozlov , то есть мне нужно скопировать содержимое из css/sb-admin-2.min.css и перенести его в scss/bootstrap.scss, если да, то к сожалению и это не помогло. При таком варианте на странице стили вовсе не отображаются

Comment: нет. в вашей папке (с исходниками) scss есть стартовый файл bootstrap.scss, а .min.css - это уже скомпилированный файл, он вам вообще не нужен

Comment: @DmitryKozlov , ну да, такой имеется,  vendor/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss и это тоже не помогло, но взяв scss например nav-bar-a и переделав его в css(sassmeister) и подключив его вместо аналогичного scss, получилось редактировать, что собственно и требовалось. Буду дальше работать в этом направлении, спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/350886/ там есть процесс сборки с помощью вебпака. Лучше собирать полностью свой css

Comment: @DmitryKozlov , понял, еще раз спасибо!